# Hi, How to Plot line on calculated price in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I am trying to plot a levels on Signal Candle , Signal Generated when 2 moving average crosses to each other.

**Code:**

```
//Version = 5.0

long = ta.ema(close,9)
short = ta.ema(close,13)

has_long = ta.crossover(long,short)[1]
has_short = ta.crossunder(long,short)[1]

plotshape(has_long,style = shape.arrowup,color = color.green,location = location.belowbar,size = size.normal)
plotshape(has_short,style = shape.arrowdown,color = color.red,location = location.abovebar,size = size.normal)


//Finding A Levels on where the Buy Signal genrated
Has_long_high = has_long ? high : 0 // High of Crossover Candle
has_long_low = has_long ? low : 0 // Lowof Crossover Candle

//Find difference and then add into the Long Signal's High Bar
has_long_diff =  (Has_long_high - has_long_low) + Has_long_high

//plot Difference in Horizantal Line format
hline(has_long_diff)
```

How can I draw levels on chart like auto fib extension and on next signal, levels will be delete from chart automatically.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should create a line with `line.new()` and delete it whenever you need with the `line.delete()` function.

```
if (draw_condition)
    my_line = line.new(...)  // Create a new line
    line.delete(my_line[1])  // Delete the old line
```